# Organizar comillas para enviar parámetro correctamente

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy tratando de enviar un parámetro a una función pero no es posible la organización de las comillas para el atributo onclick y la función addclientes.
Me aparece el siguiente error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input, y la construcción del elemento html queda mal ya que el parámetro trae varias comillas ejemplo: "{"ClienteNombre":"Nico", "DocumentNombre ":"12e3","Numero":"456"}"

```
var info = JSON.stringify(datos[i]);
    var fila = '<tr name="' + name + '">' +
                   '<td>' + cont + '</td>' +
        '<td> <input type="checkbox" name="checkclients" id = value' + i + ' style = "text-align: center;" onclick = "addclients("' + info +'")/> </td>' +
                   '<td>' + datos[i].ClienteNombre + '</td>' +
                   '<td>' + datos[i].DocumentNombre + '</td>' +
                   '<td>' + datos[i].Numero + '</td>' +
                   '<td>' + dv + '</td>' +
                   '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo recomendable es usar [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para evitar este tipo de problemas al concatenar y, de paso, hacer más legible el código:

```
var info = JSON.stringify(datos[i]);
var fila = `<tr name="${name}"> 
               <td>${cont}</td> 
               <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkclients" id="${value}${i}" style="text-align: center;" onclick="addclients('${info}')"></td> 
               <td>${datos[i].ClienteNombre}</td> 
               <td>${datos[i].DocumentNombre}</td> 
               <td>${datos[i].Numero}</td> 
               <td>${dv}</td> 
               </tr>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error al agregar el `id`, te faltan las comillas.

Para tu función debes tener cuidado con el orden, para tu caso debe ser asi

```
onclick = "addclients(\'' + info + \'')"/>
```

Nota que agregué `\'` para indicar que `'` forma parte del string